# jQuery: Validation plugin breaks when changing from jquery 1.2.6 to 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I recently upgraded from jQuery 1.2.6 to 1.3.2

Now on the page I'm using the [form validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) I get the exception:

```
[Exception... "'Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@for='registration_primary_email']' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]"  nsresult: "0x8057001e (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_STRING)"  location: "<unknown>"  data: no]
```

It doesn't happen with 1.2.6. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I had the same problem and after finding this question realized I was using an old version of the validate plugin. The latest version of the plugin (1.5.5) works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `@` selector is deprecated in jQuery 1.3.

Try removing it:

```
[for='registration_primary_email']
```